# Is Chi Squared correct for ordinal vs ordinal correlation?

Tags: r, regression, categorical-data, chi-squared-test

I have grown some bacteria using using two different methods (NUTRIENT1 and NUTRIENT2). The response variable is ordinal, categorical: No Growth, Scanty Growth, Low Growth, Moderate Growth, High Growth. I'd like to know if the Chi-squared test is a good option for comparing the correlation please.

I have made a data.frame as follows:

```
head(test)
         V1 V2 V3 V4 V5 V6 V7 V8 V9 V10 V11 V12 V13 V14 V15 V16 V17 V18 V19 V20 V21 V22 V23 V24 V25 V26 V27 V28 V29 V30 V31 V32 V33
NUTRIENT1  2  2  4  2  3  3  4  3  2   3   4   3   1   4   3   3   2   3   3   3   2   3   4   4   3   3   4   3   3   4   4   4   3
NUTRIENT2  2  2  2  2  2  3  4  3  2   1   2   3   2   2   3   2   2   4   3   3   2   2   3   3   2   3   3   3   2   3   3   3   2
         V34 V35 V36 V37 V38 V39 V40
NUTRIENT1  4   3   4   4   4   3   4
NUTRIENT2  2   2   2   3   3   3   3
```

Comment: What are v1, v2, ... , v40?

Comment: The vs are experiments (or versions)